# omit object type in the signature of an abstract method

Tags: java

I have a Model abstract class and i want to have an abstract method to set the id of the model instances. I'd like for the implementation to define what object they would like to use for the id object though. In the following example the getId() works fine but i can't override the setId() method because the signatures aren't the same: setId(Object id) vs setId(Integer id). Can i accomplish this with the use of < T > or < E > or something else. I'm not familiar how to use those.

```
abstract class Model{

    abstract public void setId(Object id); <-- the problem

    abstract public Object getId(); 
}

class SQLiteModel extends Model{

    private Integer id;

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id){ <-- the problem
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }
}
```

and what about multiple generics?

```
abstract class Model<T> {
    abstract public void setId(T id);

    abstract public T getId();

    abstract public T getSomethingElse();
}

class SQLiteModel extends Model<Integer> {
    private Integer id;

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSomethingElse(){
        return "a string";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make Model generic

```
abstract class Model<T> {
    abstract public void setId(T id);

    abstract public T getId();
}

class SQLiteModel extends Model<Integer> {
    private Integer id;

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome. I've never understood generics. Definitely need to read up on how to use them. Thanks

Comment: what if i wanted to have another object implemented by the SQLiteModel? How do you allow for multiple generics?

Comment: you can create another class eg class SQLiteStringModel extends Model<String> { ...

Comment: so you can't have another generic value in the same class then? for example, i couldn't add 'abstract public T getSomethingElse()' and then have SQLiteModel implement 'public String getSomethingElse()', correct?

Comment: no good. I updated my OP. How do i get the implementation of Model to have a valid getSomethingElse() method of a different value than Integer?

Comment: You can have a generic class with multiple generics, if that's what you're asking; just like `Map<K, V>`.

Comment: oooooooooohhhh. I've always seen the letters T, E, K. I figured those were reserved by Java. I didn't realize you could define your own placeholders and use as many as you want. makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely use multiple generics, see the [generic types tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) for more.  Best practice is to use single capital letters to indicate generic types, since they (should be) starkly contrasted to actually defined types.  However (if I understand the docs correctly) you can use any valid, unused type name as a generic type when defining a class.

```
abstract class Model<T, V> {
    abstract public void setId(T id);

    abstract public T getId();

    abstract public V getSomethingElse();
}

class SQLiteModel extends Model<Integer, String> {
    private Integer id;

    @Override
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSomethingElse(){
        return "a string";
    }
}
```